# How to generate a random number in 8086 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, microprocessors

I want to know if there a routine or an instruction to generate a random number using assembly
on 8086.
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: See also https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rdrand for modern x86 CPUs where `rdrand ax` is a valid instruction.  Besides the classic LCG mentioned in answers and the linked duplicate, there are things like xorshift+ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common way is to use the timestamp. In 32 bit mode it can be done by `rdtsc` instruction, in 16 bit mode: by using function 0 of BIOS interrupt 1A.

Because it's a timestamp, avoid using it frequently (because of lack of proper dispersion), and use it as seed for an pseudo-random number generator. When you need just one random value, you can use the timestamp directly.

Usually a simple pseudo-random number generator is enough:

```
static int seed = now();
seed = (seed * LARGE_PRIME1) % LARGE_PRIME2;
```

And there is also [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation)

Comment: OK,Please send me URL for pseudo-random number generator that you mean.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good answer to this exact question on Yahoo! Answers:

> I suspect the point here is to learn
> to write assembly language. Here's the
> instruction set
> (http://www.emu8086.com/assembler_tutorial/8086_instruction_set.html)
> You have all the instructions you need
> to perform the equation you need to
> generate pseudo-random numbers except
> the 'mod' instruction, which you'll
> have to write a subroutine for. Pay
> particular attention to the
> limitations on the MUL and DIV
> instructions. "store in a separate
> file" isn't implicit in the
> instruction set. You'll have to better
> understand what's wanted here. "File"
> and "Print" are concepts related to
> operating system; they're forms of
> output in this case.
>
> from http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081030112909AAmjEsp

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in Agner Fog's pseudo random number generators (some of which are written in assembly) [here](http://www.agner.org/random/).